# Content Repository recommendation

Tags: rest

I am badly looking for recommendations for a content repository solution (not sure if that's the correct word ) to be used in our B2B web product.

We want to make available a vast set of binary content (about 40,000 files with varying sizes from 2-25KB ) that could be browsed and selected by the users of our product. The user will then typically choose a subset of them as an input to a service running on our web product.

**Main features looking for**

1. REST API support for searching, selecting/downloading the files
2. Ease of update of the repository contents.  e.g Can add 1000 more files on top of 40k files without causing any service disruption
3. Support for access control & auth control for the file contents
4. Can run the repository as a separate service on a different server (customer premise) & plug this into the product
5. Scalable - Overtime we look to add 100,000 of binary files